# Python: 3 Error Handling inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a class and function. the function is creating a new object and executing other operations and returns the object.

```py
class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self, element):
        
        self.item = element
        self.before = None
        self.after = None
        
    def __str__(self):

        
        if self.before is None:
            return f'Previous node : {None}, item : {self.item}, Next node : {self.after.item};' 
        
        elif self.after is None:
            return f'Previous node : {self.before.item}, item : {self.item}, Next node : {None};'
        
        else:
            return f'Previous node : {self.before.item}, item : {self.item}, Next node : {self.after.item};'

def addToHeadDLL(element, head):

    try:
        name = DoublyLinkedList(element)

    except NameError:
        print('Please enter correct parameters')

    else:
        head.before = name
        name.after = head
        print('List added to Head')
        return name

a = DoublyLinkedList(1)
b = DoublyLinkedList(2)

a.after = b
b.before = a

c = addToHeadDLL(3, a) #Works

d = addToHeadDLL(4, e) #Produces NameError
```

When NameError occurs it has to print "Please enter correct parameters". But the output is like this,

```
List added to Head
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/JBallipalli/Desktop/Codes/dll.py", line 43, in <module>
    d = addToHeadDLL(4, e)
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

Please help me solve this...

***EDIT:***
It's not that try-except- else not run in function.  Check the following code. it does run.

```py
import os

def openfolder(dir):
    """Opens folder in file explorer

    Args:
        dir (str): path of the folder
    """

    os.startfile(dir)

def access(dir):
    """Checking access to the given directory

    Args:
        dir (str): directory path

    Returns:
        bool, list: status, list of files & folders in the directory path
    """
    try:
        filesList = os.listdir(dir)

    except PermissionError:
        print(f'No permission to access {os.path.basename(dir)}')
        print(f'Please delete the file in {os.path.basename(dir)} manually')

        folder = input('Do you wanna open folder in file explorer? type y/n : ')

        if folder[0].lower() == 'y':
            openfolder(dir)

        return False, None

    else:
        return True, filesList

path = r'C:\Users\JBallipalli\Recent' # raises PermissionError
permission, files = access(path)
```

and check the output:

```
No permission to access Recent
Please delete the file in Recent manually
Do you wanna open folder in file explorer? type y/n :
```

The only difference between these two functions is above (DoublyLinkedList) code calls class inside a function and other doesn't. I want to know why its behaviour like that?

my Python version : 3.7.6

Comment: what is `e`, where do you define it?

Comment: The function never gets involved, it can't be called because `e` doesn't exist.

Comment: The line in the `try` will never raise a `NameError` so it is pointless. The `NameError` is being raised before the function is even called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NameError` is returned when you're calling function, as python doesn't know what to pass as `e`.
It never gets to the exception handling part in `addToHeadDLL`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `try` and `except` in function,

If You want `NameError` then call function `addToHeadDLL` in try block.

Like that

```
try:
    d = addToHeadDLL(4, e) #Produces NameError
except:
    print("Name error")
```

Comment: Yeah I got it...Thanks

Comment: Your Edited code works because you pass a valid argument to access function i.e, 'path'. If you call addToHeadDLL( ) with valid arguments then it will also work and will execute try and except block. @Rorschach

Answer (score 0):

To add to what everyone have said, you could modify you code like the sample below to fit your use case...

This time, you handle the error at function level...

```
def addToHeadDLL(element, head):
    name = DoublyLinkedList(element)

    if not isinstance(head, type(name)):
        raise NameError('Please enter correct parameters')

    head.before = name
    name.after = head
    print('List added to Head')

    return name

a = DoublyLinkedList(1)
b = DoublyLinkedList(2)

a.after = b
b.before = a

try:
    addToHeadDLL(4, e)
except NameError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: I modified ***if not isinstance(head, type(name)): print('From func Please enter correct parameters')***, and output is *'name 'e' is not defined'*. that means if statement was not executed.